# Drop AWS Athena table with `.` in the name

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I had a client upload a malformed table with a name like `foo.bar` into an Athena instance. What syntax can I use to drop the table? If I try

```
drop table if exists `foo.bar`
```

The command silently fails, presumably because the parser interprets `foo` as the database name. If I try adding the database name explicitly as

```
drop table if exists dbname."foo.bar"
```

or

```
drop table if exists dbname.`foo.bar`
```

I get a parse error from Athena.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Glue console to remove the table from there so I was wondering if it's possible to drop such a table via Athena SQL. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can run `aws athena list-table-metadata` to see how the name is stored in the database? ([Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/list-table-metadata.html))

Comment: Presto follows the SQL standard, where double quotes are used for such escaping. I wonder why `drop table if exists dbname."foo.bar"` have not worked but I would try just `drop table if exists "foo.bar"`

Comment: what's the error you are encountering and actual dbname? This also could be causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could do drop table `database."foo.bar"`
You need backticks to drop delta tables in Athena and "" to capture foo.bar as one word.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't have access to the Glue console you can use the the AWS CLI to delete the table directly using the Glue API:

```
aws glue delete-table --database-name dbname --name foo.bar
```